# Google Compute Engine not acceping password set

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am using google compute engine to create a VM instance. When I login using SSH or gcloud, it asks me to set a password. When I try to login using that password, it says authentication not successful and terminates. I have looked all around the internet but couldn't find the solution. I have tried this numerous times now but still the same result. Is anyone else facing this problem? Does anyone has a solution for this?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instance.

Answer (score 1):

ssh login to you instance through google cloud console

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

there is a configuration called

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

change to

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

restarat ssh service